# How to make entire lightning component clickable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to take some action on click of a component itself.I have a list of components out of which I want to select one and display that particular data, for which I want to make it clickable. How can we make entire component clickable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just place the contents of your component in a span or div:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute ... />
    <div onclick="{!c.clickHandler}">
        main content here
    </div>
</aura:component>
```